# (Linux) Python is stopped - preventing me to start a Service

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, httpd, django, build-server

I'm currently running CentOS 5.5 on my machine, and I'm trying to setup a Build Server using Django, MySQL and Apache.

I have basically no experience with any of those, and I've been researching on Google every single time I encounter a new error. So far it's been conclusive, but I'm stuck at the final step now.

```
# service httpd start
Starting httpd: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for jmaxime-linux
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, 
using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
                                                  [  OK  ]
# service mysqld start
Starting MySQL: :                                 [  OK  ]
# service buildserverd start
Starting buildserverd :                           [  OK  ]
```

So apparently everything went alright. But then I get the following:

```
# service buildserverd status
python is stopped
```

So apparently my buildserverd service hasn't been started properly, and I don't know why.
The dependencies to make this service work are correct, the django ones too.

What am I doing wrong?

Note:

```
# uname -a
Linux jmaxime-linux 2.6.18-238.19.1.el5 #1 SMP Fri Jul 15 07:31:24 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# python -V
Python 2.7.2
# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.3
Server built:   May  4 2011 06:51:15
```

I have no idea what else to include to make it easier for you guys. Sorry if the question ends up being irresolvable because I made some mistakes in configuration files :/

Also, I've added the following lines in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/cfgmgmt
    ServerName   jmaxime-linux
    ErrorLog     logs/cfgmgmt_error.log
    TransferLog  logs/cfgmgmt_access.log
    SetEnv PYTHON_EGG_CACHE /tmp

    AliasMatch /([^/]*\.css) /var/www/cfgmgmt/media/css/$1
    AliasMatch /([^/]*\.js) /var/www/cfgmgmt/media/$1
    AliasMatch /([^/]*\.png) /var/www/cfgmgmt/media/img/$1
    AliasMatch /([^/]*\.gif) /var/www/cfgmgmt/media/img/$1
    AliasMatch /([^/]*\.ico) /var/www/cfgmgmt/media/img/$1

    Alias /media/ /var/www/cfgmgmt/media

    <Directory /var/www/cfgmgmt/media>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jmaxime/workspace/BuildServer_mjulien/django.wsgi

    <Directory /home/jmaxime/workspace/BuildServer_mjulien>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

As requested: Tail of Apache log:

```
[Sun Aug 07 04:02:03 2011] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for jmaxime-linux
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
```

Thank you.

Comment: This should be moved to Serverfault.

Comment: How do I do that?
Or was that comment for mods?

Comment: The comment was for people who can vote for moving questions (there are five votes from different people required to move)

Comment: Nevermind, still doesn't work.
Apparently Apache would be the problem, since this message keeps appearing when I retsrat httpd: Starting httpd: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for jmaxime-linux
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName I'm guessing it doesn't use the correct ServerName. I'll look into that.
Sorry for writing an answer - this should have been a comment.

Comment: This is not a Python question but buildserver question. Please remove Python and retag as buildserver/django to get answers.

Comment: Please post the tail end of apache's log and buildservers logs

Comment: Also post the init script for buildserverd?